# Understanding various types of motion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, diffusion, brownian-motion

In classical statistical mechanics, given a system of particles, one often goes about classifying various dynamics (or types of motion) the system may exhibit on different time scales, but studying the time dependence of the average displacement vector squared. For example if the dependence is quadratic in time, we say the system is ballistic, and similarly if it is linear in time, we say it is diffusive. In other words

- $\langle \lvert \mathbf{r}(t)\rvert^2\rangle \propto t^2 \Rightarrow$ ballistic motion
- $\langle \lvert \mathbf{r}(t)\rvert^2\rangle \propto t \Rightarrow$ diffusive motion

---

**Questions**:

1. Mathematically I understand the classification is given by the power of $t$ (this goes on, e.g. we can have subdiffusive motions etc), but purely from a physical point of view, how do the two aforementioned types of motion differ? For example, by diffusive motion, in contrast to ballistic, do we mean there are random forces involved? (e.g. particles in solvent)
2. What does it mean that on different time scales, the system may follow different types of motion? e.g. in short times ballistic, and the longer term behaviour diffusive.
3. Finally, why is the average squared displacement $\langle \lvert \mathbf{r}(t)\rvert^2\rangle$ a sufficient measure for qualifying the types of motion?

Comment: In short time scales particles don't collide/interact much, thus their motion is approximately defined by F=0, i.e. r = vt. For long timescales, the particles collide and change direction constantly, and behave like Brownian motion. There often are for example subdiffusive regimes in between where the particles "rattle in a cage" so that they bounce off of neighboring particles never moving too much until in fact they escape the neighborhood and get trapped in another.

Comment: @alarge thanks so much for your comment, this is exactly the types of arguments I am looking for. Specially the short time scales, now I see why it is often considered to be ballistic. Would you be so kind and expand this into an answer with more supplement on the diffusive part?

Comment: Hi again! You may want to take a look at http://users-phys.au.dk/fogedby/statphysII/notes/Brownian-motion.pdf. It provides very nice details (sorry, previous comments didn't show for me when I typed this). See especially eqs.(12)-(14).

Comment: @udrv hi there, good to hear from you mate :) thanks for the notes, so useful indeed! I think I ve got it now. Although i have to admit i find it a bit weird the sense of putting gamma at interplay with time. So is gamma (which is the friction coef divided by mass) or its inverse here, giving us some sort of time scale? Is there a way to interpret that time scale physically? e.g. the average time between successive collisions. Still pondring eq 12 at the moment.

Comment: Yes, $\gamma$ is definitely setting the time scale. If you just go back at Langevin eq.(1) and ignore $F$, you can see that $\alpha$ sets the rate for velocity decay under friction. Basically ${\dot v} = -(\alpha/m) v$ tells that $v(t) \sim v(0) \text{exp}[-(\alpha/m)t]$ as a result of fluid drag. Eventually drag may be attributed to collisions, but in this case  collisions are accounted for by the random force $F$, which maintains average energy at thermal level (equipartition theorem). Otherwise drag alone would quickly bring the particle to rest wrt fluid.

Comment: @udrv by the way for me, your comments along with the pdf you linked, resolved most of my questions asked in this post, so in principle I could delete the post, unless you want to write an answer to it nonetheless, for future users, if you see the question as that important. Otherwise, let me know and I ll just remove it. Thanks again

Comment: You are very welcome :) But why would you remove the post? I'm sure it will prove useful to somebody else later.